# $e$ and natural logarithms

Tags: logarithms

How would you solve $6xe^{2x}+3e^{2x}=0$ for $x$

I tried:

$\ln(e^{2x})=\ln(1/6x+3)$

$2x=\ln(1)-\ln(6x+3)$

$2x=-\ln(6x+3)$

but then I am stuck there.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't solve that $-$ it's not an equation. Do you mean $6xe^{2x}+3e^{2x}=0$?

Comment: Do you mean $6xe^{2x} = 3e^{2x}$?

Comment: sorry I meant 6xe^(2x)+3e^(2x)=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$3e^{2x}(2x+1)=0 \Rightarrow x=-\frac{1}{2}, \text{ as } e^{2x} \neq 0, \forall x$$

Comment: can you please explain a bit more the answer Evinda, I am not familiar with the reasoning behind the answer: "as e2x≠0,∀x"

Comment: From the equality $3e^{2x}(2x+1)=0$ we get: $e^{2x}=0$ or $2x+1=0$..But, $e^{2x}=0$ cannot be true for any $x$,because we know that $e^x>0 , \forall x$.Therefore,it must be $2x+1=0 \Rightarrow x=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much for that!